# Force any Link From Nested Iframe to Open in New Window

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink, target

I am displaying some 3rd party banners inside an Iframe which are loading through `javascript`. Banners are showing inside iframe and links are openning to new window when I browse the url myself. Problem is when I am trying to advertise the url to different ptc sites. Basically this site show url inside iframe. so when my url which is itself an iframe loading inside another iframe, clicking not working. Below is my current code

```
<base target="_blank"> //in head section

<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-downloads" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['ad_url'];?>" frameborder="0" id="pgl" name="pgl" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%" onmouseover="on_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="on_mouseout(this)"></iframe>
```

As i see the source of the page that embeds my iframe found below code

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms" id="surfsite" name="surfsite" src="https://sitename.com/sitename.php?" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

how can I make this working

Comment: Where is the code of the other page, that embeds your iframe into an additional level of iframe - and what sandbox attributes are set on _that_?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: The other site’s iframe does not have `allow-popups` set, so while _your_ iframe is allowed to open new windows on its own, it isn’t any more from within the context of that second iframe.

Comment: got it, is there any solution for this to override?

Comment: Not from your end. The point of sandboxing is to give the page that embeds your content, control over what your content is allowed to do, within the context of that page. If you could undermine that from your end now, the whole concept would not make sense to begin with.